# Angular 4 disable file chooser for HTML5 camera attribute on desktops

Tags: html, angular

Hi I have a file uploader application which uploads images.
I'm using HTML5 file chooser-

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;" capture="camera">
```

I'm getting file chooser while using this app on desktop.
I wanted to disable file chooser for this application if not opened in mobile.

HTML5 by default opens file chooser on desktop.
I wanted to open camera on desktop or disable this application on desktop.

I don't want application to work on the chrome dev tools mobile view.

Any suggestions how to implement it?